# Binding a class loses it's static properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given

```
class someClass {
  constructor (str) {
    console.log('created', str);
  }
  static someStatic() {
  }
}
```

we can do

```
const someBoundClass = someClass.bind(someClass, 'xxx');
const a = new someBoundClass(); // logs 'created xxx'
console.log(someClass.someStatic) // logs someStatic () {}
console.log(someBoundClass.someStatic) // logs undefined
```

What's happening behind the scenes causing me to be unable to access static properties on a bound class? Is there any way to achieve the desired bound effect without losing the static methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `bind` creates a new function object, so I'm not sure why you would expect it to have the same static properties. Remember that ES6 `class` is mostly syntactic sugar:

```
function someClass(str) {
  if (!new.target) throw "constructor must be called with new";
  console.log('created', str);
}
someClass.someStatic = function() {};

var someBoundClass = someClass.bind(null, 'xxx');
console.log(someBoundClass === someClass) // false, of course
```

As a workaround, you might be able to use subclassing:

```
class someBoundClass extends someClass { constructor(...args) { super('xxx', ...args); }}
const a = new someBoundClass(); // logs 'created xxx'
console.log(someClass.someStatic) // logs someStatic () {}
console.log(someBoundClass.someStatic) // logs someStatic () {}
```

The `someBoundClass` here inherits the static properties from `someClass`.

Comment: It seems in this case `bind()` doesn't *just* create a function. You can't for example call `someBoundClass` without `new`.

Comment: @Mark_M That's just because you cannot call the original `someClass` without `new` either, so calling the bound function will still throw. There's nothing special about this `bind` call.

Comment: yeah, the thing that made it click at least a bit for me was when I just added a property to a `function` and realized that binding that function 'loses' the property. Somehow I never 'thought' the right way about `bind` clearly :/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Javascript static vs instance, prototype keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749401/javascript-static-vs-instance-prototype-keyword)

There is a difference between setting a property to an object, what is done when using `static` and adding a method to each instance of the object, which can be done by using `someClass.prototype.someMethod` or in your case by just removing `static`.

That means `undefined` would also occur, if you try to call `someStatic` on a instance of `someClass`, which was instantiated directly by `new someClass("xxx")`.

For another approach take a look at the answer of Bergi.